# How to add data labels in each bar in stacked bar chart in chart.js?

Tags: bar-chart, chart.js, angular-chart, chart.js2

I am using a directive to use chart.js in Angular JS. 
Git Link : https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

I am interested in using stacked bar charts. How do I add data labels on the bars to display each of the bar values in the stacked bar chart?

Answer (score 0):

This example seems to provide an answer to my question . 
[Git Hub Link](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/data_label_combo-bar-line.html)

It displays the bar value labels just above the bars. 
However, I need to position the data labels at the vertical centre of the bars. So, it does provide an answer to my question. But still, more info regarding customizing it is needed.